# Activity not updating previous activity TextView

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

I have created all by myself first app for android. User has to click next activity started button that will open new activity. User will type a text there and the text will be returned to the previous screen. That text will be updated on a textview. Initially the textview will have "No text entered message" and after updating from the activity it will be new text that was entered. 
I am having the problem that textbox disappears and no message is shown when updated from new activity.

Here is my main activity

```
public static String new_message;
final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

public void new_activity(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, new_activity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!= null){
        TextView set_message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.entered_text);
        set_message.setText(new_message);
    }

}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}
public void show_text(View view){
        TextView message;
        message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showText);
        message.setText("I have been cliked now!!");
}
```

Here is my new activity java file.

```
public void return_previous(View view){
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    EditText editTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_entered);
    String text_entered = editTextBox.getText().toString();
    resultIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.new_message,text_entered);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    this.finish();
}
```

Comment: So you mean the activity in which you can enter the text works, you manage to submit the text and the app goes back to the first activity BUT the returned activity is not updated. Am i right? Why don't you add some debug log like Log.d("ResultActivity", "result returned: "+new_message);

Answer (score 2):

edit onActivityResult to match this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!= null){

        TextView set_message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.entered_text);

        //set_message.setText(new_message);
        set_message.setText(data.getStringExtra(new_message));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Can you explain me why my code wasn't working and why did you made these changes?

Comment: because when you called putString in the previous Activity it actually added this String value to some kind of "Key/Value Map" ,so you string is added to the entity with the "newMessage" as it's id .... however to retrieve this value you must use this key and get it from the calling intent (which is in this case "data")

Comment: I still didnt understand key value map part !

Comment: you weren't getting the value at all you just set the textview to an empty variable so getStringExtra(new_message) gets the value that you passed in from your second activity

Comment: this Key Value map is [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) which android uses to store the values that are sent between (services , activities .. etc)